# Google Big Query insertAll() returns successful result, but table is empty

Tags: php, laravel, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I use [package](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery) which is a part of [another package](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php).

Here is my base class for writing to google big query table:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\BigQuery;

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Dataset;
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Table;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

abstract class BigQueryTool
{
    protected Dataset $dataset;
    protected Table   $table;
    protected string  $tableName;
    protected string  $schemaPath;
    protected int     $chunkSize          = 1000;
    protected int     $maxRetries         = 1;
    protected bool    $deleteTableIfExist = false;

    public function run(BigQueryClient $bigQuery)
    {
        $this->init($bigQuery);

        $items = [];
        $data  = $this->getData();
        $count = count($data);

        foreach ($data as $key => $info) {
            $item = [
                'data' => $this->mapData($key, $info),
            ];

            if ($this->deleteTableIfExist) {
                $item['insertId'] = $key + 1;
            }

            $items[] = $item;
        }

        if (count($items) > 0) {
            $chunks  = collect($items)->chunk($this->chunkSize);
            $inserts = 0;

            foreach ($chunks->toArray() as $key => $chunk) {
                $response = $this->table->insertRows($chunk, [
                    'maxRetries' => $this->maxRetries,
                ]);

                if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
                    $inserts++;

                    Log::info('[ ' . class_basename($this) . ' ] - Success Response', [
                        'info'           => $response->info(),
                        'failedRows'     => $response->failedRows(),
                        'original_chunk' => $chunk,
                    ]);
                } else {
                    Log::error('[ ' . class_basename($this) . ' ] - Failed Insert', [
                        'extras' => [
                            'info' => $response->info(),
                            'rows' => $response->failedRows(),
                        ],
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected function init(BigQueryClient $bigQuery)
    {
        $this->setDataset($bigQuery);
        $this->setTable($this->tableName, $this->schemaPath);
    }

    protected function setDataset(BigQueryClient $bigQuery)
    {
        $this->dataset = $bigQuery->dataset(
            config('bigquery.dataset'),
            config('bigquery.project'),
        );
    }

    protected function setTable(string $tableName, string $schemaPath)
    {
        $table = $this->dataset->table($tableName);

        if ($table->exists() && $this->deleteTableIfExist) {
            $table->delete();
        }

        if (!$table->exists()) {
            $table = $this->dataset->createTable($tableName, [
                'schema' => $this->getSchema($schemaPath),
            ]);
        }

        $this->table = $table;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $schemaPath
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getSchema(string $schemaPath)
    {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents(database_path($schemaPath)));
    }

    /**
     * @return array|Collection
     */
    abstract protected function getData();

    /**
     * @param mixed                   $key
     * @param string|Collection|array $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    abstract protected function mapData($key, $data): array;
}
```

We use main method `run()` and it should write all data (rows) to GBQ table.

Sometimes it works as it should! BUT!! Sometimes we get a message that everything is OK, but in fact the table is empty! There is no single record. API response errors is empty. IDK how can it be.

May be someone has the same issue?

Comment: From BigQuery service perspective, if you have access, you can visit https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll (on the right side "Try this API" ) to manually send request *directly* to BigQuery. Let me know if you will have a repro this way.

Comment: Make sure that insertID is correct, I had an issue with a similar problem. Then streaming buffer shows up in table in a while, so you might not have the data immediately available.

Comment: @YunZhang I tried submitting a request just now (of course I tried submitting a request earlier through this form). It does not work correctly. I may be able to insert data the first time, or maybe the third or fifth. Same behavior as in my code. It doesn't depend on the code as I understand it.

Comment: @Pentium10 I have checked this field. The data is correct there. As I explained above: my queries work as expected, but sometimes they don't (and I don't get the error). Can you provide a link to the source where it says that the data in the table is not updated immediately?